# Jenkins Pipeline: abort an input in a stage cannot trigger the aborted post action of that stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My purpose is simple, just want to do some post actions in a stage when user click 'Abort' button in the input step of that stage. I've read some docs from jenkins.io and found there seems an implicit way for doing this by using the post directive. So I make some simple test below:

First is this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            input {
                message 'Proceed?'
                ok 'yes'
                submitter 'admin'
            }
            steps {
                echo "helloworld"
            }
            post {
                aborted {
                    echo "stage test has been aborted"
                }
            }            
        }
    }
    post {
        aborted {
            echo "pipeline has been aborted"
        }
    }
}
```

If I click Abort button, the log output will only show:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] input
Proceed?
yes or Abort
Aborted by admin
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] echo
pipeline has been aborted
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Rejected by SYSTEM
Finished: ABORTED
```

which means Input Abort only trigger the post action part of the pipeline but not the part within that stage.
Then I try another one:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {            
            steps {
                sh "sleep 15"
            }
            post {
                aborted {
                    echo "stage test has been aborted"
                }
            }            
        }
    }
    post {
        aborted {
            echo "pipeline has been aborted"
        }
    }
}
```

I abort this job within 15 seconds, and output will show

```
[Pipeline] { (hide)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] sh
+ sleep 15
Sending interrupt signal to process
Aborted by admin
Terminated
script returned exit code 143
Post stage
[Pipeline] echo
stage test has been aborted
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] echo
pipeline has been aborted
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: ABORTED
```

Which means the post aborted action part in a stage could be triggered.

How can I do some post actions when abort an input step within a stage, not the whole pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

I think I figure out what's the difference between the above two examples and how to solve this problem myself :).

It seems like the Post actions in a stage will only be triggered when the related Steps section's currentResult is matched but not the Input section above. So I make a little change and it works. That is make the Input section a script inside the Steps section.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    input message: 'Proceed?', ok: 'Yes', submitter: 'admin'
                }
                echo "helloworld"
            }
            post {
                aborted{
                    echo "test stage has been aborted"
                }
            }            
        }
    }
    post {
        aborted {
            echo "pipeline has been aborted"
        }
    }
}
```

When click Abort button, the output log is:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipeline-demo
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] input
Proceed?
Yes or Abort
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
Post stage
[Pipeline] echo
test stage has been aborted
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] echo
pipeline has been aborted
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Rejected by admin
Finished: ABORTED
```

which satisfys me:). I can compose a complex pipeline with user confirmation and auto rolling back now. Hope it also help you.